# Can I merge Git branches without checking one of them out first?

Tags: git, git-merge

Is there a way to merge a branch regardless of what branch you have checked out? Does Git support merges with --source and --destination flags?

I am looking for a simple command that supports something straight forward like this:

```
git merge --sourcebranch --destinationbranch
```

It's terribly awkward to have to move between branches to merge things.  I would much rather just merge branches regardless of what branch I have checked out right now.

Comment: I think there was some work being made in that direction, but I do not think it would be available yet (at least, I haven't heard anything about it being available). However, if you need to do a merge that is not on what you have checked out at the time and you don't want to lose the current state of your working tree, you can create a new working tree (inside the local repo you are working on) so that you can do that and then you can remove the working tree. Check `git help worktree`.

Comment: What do you want to happen when there are conflicts?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the low-level [`git merge-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-tree) command. The man page even has an example of what you are trying to do in the [usage notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-tree#_usage_notes) section:

```
NEWTREE=$(git merge-tree --write-tree $BRANCH1 $BRANCH2)
test $? -eq 0 || die "There were conflicts..."
NEWCOMMIT=$(git commit-tree $NEWTREE -p $BRANCH1 -p $BRANCH2)
git update-ref $BRANCH1 $NEWCOMMIT
```

Make that into a shell function and you're good to go:

```
my_merge() {
  NEWTREE=$(git merge-tree --write-tree "$1" "$2")
  if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo 'There were conflicts...' >&2
    return 1
  }
  NEWCOMMIT=$(echo "Merge branch '$2' into $1" | git commit-tree "$NEWTREE" -p "$1" -p "$2")
  git update-ref "$1" "$NEWCOMMIT"
}
```

And use it:

```
my_merge first_branch second_branch
```

`first_branch` will be forwarded to the new, merged commit; `second_branch` remains unchanged. If there are conflicts, the operation is aborted and nothing happens.

Comment: This is great. Reading this answer is a similar feeling to watching a great magic trick, and then watching a video explaining how it's performed. :)

Comment: @TTT it's there in the docs: "The log message is read from the standard input, unless -m or -F options are given." But I missed that too; it should be mentioned in the answer

Comment: @TTT :D well, it works™, it just sits there waiting for the user to type in a commit message. I have updated the function to provide a default commit message based on the branch names :)

Comment: (I deleted my other comments since you already fixed it.)

Comment: Now your answer is better than the Git docs. ;)